# Undefined reference despite linking in OpenFEC-library

Tags: c++, gcc

I get this problem when referring to OpenFEC (openfec.org)-functions in my code:

```
anders@ubuntu:~/workspace/fectest$ gcc -L../openfeclib/ -l'openfec' -I../openfeclib fectest.cpp
/tmp/ccEXLrdc.o: In function `main':
fectest.cpp:(.text+0x17a): undefined reference to `of_create_codec_instance(of_session**, of_codec_id_t, unsigned char, unsigned int)'
fectest.cpp:(.text+0x2db): undefined reference to `of_set_fec_parameters(of_session*, of_parameters*)'
fectest.cpp:(.text+0x347): undefined reference to `of_build_repair_symbol(of_session*, void**, unsigned int)'
fectest.cpp:(.text+0x395): undefined reference to `of_release_codec_instance(of_session*)'
collect2: ld returnerade avslutningsstatus 1
```

The c-files containing these functions are included in the openfec-library.

The command `nm ../openfeclib/libopenfec.so | grep of_release_codec` gives:

```
000000000001a294 T of_release_codec_instance
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Libraries should always be after the source/object files. In other words, put `-lopenfec` last on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The error remains though:
anders@ubuntu:~/workspace/fectest$ gcc fectest.cpp -L../openfeclib/ -I../openfeclib/ -I../openfeclib -lopenfec
/tmp/ccqNtnWi.o: In function `main':
fectest.cpp:(.text+0x17a): undefined reference to `of_create_codec_instance(of_session**, of_codec_id_t, unsigned char, unsigned int)'
fectest.cpp:(.text+0x2db): undefined reference to `of_set_fec_parameters(of_session*, of_parameters*)'
fectest.cpp:(.text+0x347): undefined reference to `of_build_repair_symbol(of_session*, void**, unsigned int)'
fectest.cpp:(.text+0x395): undefined reference t

Comment: Did you use `-lopenfec` or `-l'openfec'` in your compile options ? Because the latter is incorrect ?

Comment: Appleman1234, Thanks for the input and the correction! I have also tried with -lopenfec and it generated the same errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was (finally!!) referred to the solution in the FFMpeg-mailing list: http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#I_0027m-using-FFmpeg-from-within-my-C_002b_002b-application-but-the-linker-complains-about-missing-symbols-which-seem-to-be-available_002e

Quote: "FFmpeg is a pure C project, so to use the libraries within your C++ application you need to explicitly state that you are using a C library. You can do this by encompassing your FFmpeg includes using extern "C"."

I applied the same solution to my FFMpeg-problem to the OpenFEC-library-problem.